Has it ever been considered to raise the 30K character limit for answers?
Most questions can be comprehensively answered within the confines of 30K characters, however there are the occasional comprehensive answers that could benefit from additional comprehensive info that are unable to because of the 30K character limit.

I've come up against the limit several times, and when I do, I've had to get creative with how to edit small things to decrease the content below the 30K limit 

In some of my more comphrensive answers, markdown alone makes up a significant portion of the content to the tune of thousands of characters since I make heavy use of markdown and man page links; for example:

In this answer, I've had to remove content when making updates to it since it sits at 29,999 characters
In this answer, I had to limit the content to only one of four complex, applicable scenarios (Automate Windows Setup, Configuration Set, Distribution Share, Deployment Share) because I was up against the 30K character limit at 29,956 characters
In this answer, I was unable to include the content of a Windows-formatted openssl.cnf since the answer was already at 29,596 characters without it (since the answer wholly relied on this specific customized openssl.cnf, it made sense to include the contents within the answer, even though it'll always be available on my GitHub) 

A solution could be to exclude markdown and weblink addresses from the character limit.

It has been asked in the past, and always [tag:status-declined]

@DavidPostill Thanks for letting me know! =]

You would have to make the feature request on meta stack exchange. Chances of it being seen by a developer here is small.

@Ramhound Will do, thanks for the advice! =]

This has been posted on Meta StackExchange as well - should I leave this question open or close it?
